# HTML line break inside a <script> for a function

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

Within a  I create another  with a function inside. The function requires a line break so that it is "recognized". If I use `<br />` the function is recognized but Javascript gives the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'". How do I make a linebreak that it is recognized in HTML but not recognized as an error by js?

```
//good for html and bad for js cause the error pops up
downloadfunction.innerHTML = 'function download' + i + '(){**<br />**document.getElementById("delcon' +  i + '").checked = true;}';

//bad for html and good for js (But here the function does not work because it is not recognized as a function.)
downloadfunction.innerHTML = 'function download' + i + '(){document.getElementById("delcon' +  i + '").checked = true;}';

//stuff like \n isnt working
```

I tried to create a function in a loop with variable function names (hence the "i") in a . The loop is also in a  due to other reasons and cannot be swapped out.

Comment: The function should not require a line break. `\n` is a line break in JS. `<br>` is not. You've misidentified the problem so the real solution isn't clear.

Comment: Dynamically generating function names as globals is a terrible idea (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5187652/19068)) as is generating them as strings instead of using closures to create them.

Comment: Functions need a line break after the "{" for clarity. The function will not work without it. I tried it without linebreak.

Comment: Adding a line break after `{` does make the function clearer for people reading the source code. It is **not** required for the function to work. https://jsbin.com/sutijoqaje/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use normal line breaks inside a Javascript string if it is delimited by `` `...` ``. The following snippet illustrates what can be done:

```js
var i = 1;
document.getElementById("downloadfunction").textContent = `function download${i}() {
  document.getElementById("delcon${i}").checked = true;
}`;
```

```html
<script id="downloadfunction"></script>
<input id="delcon1" type="checkbox"/>
<button onclick="download1()">Check</button>
```

But as Quentin pointed out in the comment, rather than generating functions `download1()`, `download2()`, consider using *one* function with a parameter `download(i)`.

Comment: Nice Try but "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')" pops up

Comment: It works if you run my code snippet. You may have to adapt it for your code, of course.

Comment: ur code snippet works, i am working on it to implement it to my code